# $C_G^n(g) \triangleleft C_G^{n + 1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a group. $g \in G$. Define $\{C_G^{(n)}(g)\}_{n = 0}^\infty$ as a series of subgroups of $G$, defined by the following recurrence relation:

$$C_G^n(g) = \begin{cases} \langle \{h \in G| [h, g] \in C_G^{n-1}\} \rangle & \quad n \geq 1 \\ E & \quad n = 0 \end{cases}$$

It is not hard to see, that this series is ascending and that $C_G^1(g) = C_G(g)$ is the centraliser of $g$ in $G$.

The question is:

Is it always true, that $C_G^n(g) \triangleleft C_G^{n + 1}(g)$?

For $n = 0$ it is obviously true. For $n > 0$ it is sufficient to prove, that $\forall a \in C_G^n(G) \forall b \in G ([b, g] \in C_G^n(g) \to b^{-1}ab \in C_G^n(g))$. However, this does not seem to be any easier.

Comment: Exactly, so what possible reason could there be to conjecture that $C_G(g) \unlhd C_G^2(g)$? Anyway, the answer to your question is no. Try a few examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is false.

If it were true, then it would have resulted in all left-Engel elements of the group to lie in subnormal abelian subgroups and thus in the locally-nilpotent radical of the corresponding group. However not all left-Engel elements satisfy that condition, as proven in “Left $3$-Engel elements in groups of exponent $5$” by G. Traustason.